# Swapping values of two variables without using a third one- Array

Tags: c++, swap

I am writing a program which takes user input to determine pair of numbers and swaps values of all the pairs entered by the user.

For example:

User wants to enter 3 pairs, then he would enter 3 followed by pairs:

3
1 2
3 4
5 6

Output:

2 1
4 3
6 5

My program is giving proper output but instead of taking all pairs at once, it takes them one by one and gives the output. I have a vague idea that this can be resolved by using array but not sure how. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x, y, p, i;
   //int a [100], b[100];
    printf ("How many pairs?\n");
    scanf ("%d", &p);
    for(i=1; i<=p; i++)
    {
       printf ("Enter two values:\n");
       scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);

       x = x + y;  
       y = x - y;  
       x = x - y;
      //a[i]=x;
      //b[i]=y;



      printf("\n");
      printf("After Swapping: x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Currently the output looks like:

How many pairs?
2

Enter two values:
2 3

After swapping x= 3 and y=2

Enter two values:
4 5

After swapping x= 5 and y=4. I want it to take all 4 values together and display output.

Comment: sidenote: I would recommend to use a temporary variable to do the swapping. `int temp=x;x=y;y=temp;` or use `std::swap`.

Comment: to fix your problem, read all data into a `std::vector`, do the swapping, and output the data.

Comment: In this case, the third variable will be held in a CPU register, and cost you NOTHING. And the code `int z = x; x = y; y = z;` will be simpler than the one you got. And before anyone comments on this, using `std::swap(x, y)` will do exactly that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them in an array (like you were trying to in some of the commented code), and then swap them one by one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x, y, p, i;
    printf ("How many pairs?\n");
    scanf ("%d", &p);
    int a[p],b[p];
    for(i=0; i<p; i++)
    {
        printf ("Enter values for pair %d:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d %d",&a[i],&b[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<p; i++)
    {
        x = a[i];
        y=b[i];
        x = x + y;  
        y = x - y;  
        x = x - y;
        printf("Pair %d After Swapping: x = %d, y = %d\n", i+1, x, y);
    }

     return 0;
}
```

Try it here: http://goo.gl/5JJ7i3

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are looking for something like this (you need only one array; you can directly store the values in swapped order):

```
for(i=0; i<p; i++) {
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    a[2*i+1]=x;
    a[2*i]=y;
}
for(i=0; i<2*p; i++) {
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're working on C so I've only used C headers. One way to do this is to first find out how many pairs there are, dynamically allocate space as is applicable, fill the array with the input integers, swap them, and then print them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Enter numbers: ");

    /* Get the number of pairs. */
    int prs;
    scanf_s("%i",&prs);

    /* Create a dynamic array. */
    prs*=2;
    int *A = (int*) malloc(prs*sizeof(int));

    /* Read the integers into the array. */
    int i=0;
    for(;i!=prs;scanf_s("%i",&A[i++]));

    /* Swap. */
    int j=0;
    for(;j!=prs;j+=2)
    {
        int tmp = A[j];
        A[j] = A[j+1];
        A[j+1] = tmp;
    }

    /* Print. */
    for(i=0;i!=j;printf("%i ",A[i++]));
    printf("\n");
}
```

Cheers ! If you're interested in really getting good, try [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) book.

Comment: also it's a good idea to write a wrapper for `malloc`. Since this is an example I tried minimizing clutter, but in a real world situation you would write a function called `Malloc` which returns the space allocated by `malloc` if successful or an error-message otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added a C++ tag, I'll suggest a simple STL solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
  std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> Vec;
  std::pair<int,int> Pr;
  int n;
  std::cin>>n;  //no. of pairs

  while(n--){
    std::cin>>Pr.second>>Pr.first;  //pair of elements stored in swapped locations
    Vec.push_back(Pr);
  }

  for(auto element : Vec){
    std::cout<<element.first<<" "<<element.second<<" ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```